# Is there any gem for client side filtering of search keywords?

Tags: javascript, ruby, filtering

Is there any ruby gem for client side filtering of view based on what is typed in the search bar? I have seen a ruby gem for client side validation (client_side_validations).So I was wondering if there is any gem for filtering as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the below link.

http://www.ddarrensmith.com/blog/2012/05/17/ruby-on-rails-client-side-validation-with-validation-helpers-and-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score -1):

You just need a dynamic query to get the desired filtered view based on your search text.

First, you'll need to add a search action to your controller. This could be like this:

```
def search
  if params[:query]
   @products = Product.search(params[:query])
  else
   @products = []
  end
end
```

Next, on any of the views you can add this bit of code. This is basically a search box.

```
<form action='/search'>
<input name="query" type="text" />
<input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
```

Then you create a view called search for your controller. Not the best view but you can use whatever you like and modify it to your liking. So the code below is your search.rhtml.

```
<% if @products.empty? %>
    <span>There were no results for your query</span><br/><br/>
<% else %>

<% for product in @products %>
Result: <% product.title %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

So, just a form which accesses the search action in your controller and sends the parameter called query to it. Quite simple.